# If there are four weeks,how to store the data of single week in the database by selecting the week?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to store the dates for particular week in the database.
E.G: If 1-3-2015 to 7-3-2015 is week 1,then I want to store 8-3-2015 to 14-3-2015 as week 2 and etc. How can I store this as weeks in database.

Comment: If you are asking for such a inbuilt data type that will hold only this kind of information in SQL server then there is no such thing exist in SQL or C#.

Comment: Then how can I achieve this thing ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Table :

`TableName WeekInfo'

`WeekId int`

`StartDate DateTime`

`EndDate DateTime`

and then use the WeeKInfo Table's `WeekId` in your actual table.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
declare @date datetime = getdate()
declare @wkid int

set @wkid=(select datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, @date)/7 * 7)/7 + 1)

insert into table_name (ekid,date1) values(@wkid,@date)
```